# react-suneditor css not loading on production

Tags: reactjs, next.js, richtextbox, suneditor

I set up react-suneditor just as it said in the docs, using dynamic loading since I'm using Next.js.

```
import React from 'react';
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import 'suneditor/dist/css/suneditor.min.css'; // Import Sun Editor's CSS File

const SunEditor = dynamic(() => import("suneditor-react"), {
  ssr: false,
});

const MyComponent = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p> My Other Contents </p>
      <SunEditor />
    </div>
  );
};
export default MyComponent;
```

And the rich text editor works and looks fine when developing on my macbook. However when I push to my server on Heroku it totally messes up the styling. I wonder if there is an issue when loading the css?

How it looks on development:
[image]

How it looks on server:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I made it work by importing source css instead of the dist one :
`import 'suneditor/src/assets/css/suneditor.css'`
But IMHO, this is just a workaround.

I suggest to open an issue on https://github.com/mkhstar/suneditor-react

Comment: I am getting `Error: Cannot find module 'suneditor/dist/css/suneditor.min.css'` even when the file is present in the node_modules